# VueJs - Set property in child component's $options based on prop

Tags: vue.js

### Reproducible example

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-banach-tc83p?file=/src/components/ChildComponent.vue

### Background

In the project I'm working on, there are helper functions which depend on a `translationFile` property in the `$options` of the component. However, when the component is a generic one being implemented in different places, that property will be different depending on the implementation.

### What I want to do

Is there a way that I can set a property in the child component's `$options` dynamically based on the parent component?

### Helper function example

```js
  getLabel(labelKey) {
    const { translationFile } = this.$options;
    if (translationFile && labelKey) {
      return this.$tc(`${translationFile}.labels.${labelKey}`);
    } 
  },
```

this would be called from the child component (CC), hence `this.$options` would refer to the CC.
When the parent component (PC) is PC1.vue, the file it would look in would be tran1.js, when PC2.vue, then tran2.js

Comment: I can [see](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-banach-tc83p?file=/src/components/ChildComponent.vue) that you are currently using `this.$parent.$options.translationFile;`. Are you like asking for an alternative? Like a different way in which you can pass a value from parent to child?

Comment: @RotikenGisa this works in the computed properties but I need to be able to set `$options.translationFile` within the ChildComponent

Comment: What criteria would you want to use to set it? Like if the child component is the consumer of this variable, shouldn't it come from the parent so that it becomes dynamic? Kindly help me understand, then I'll be able to help

Comment: @RotikenGisa I have added an example of a helper function, which should help clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with.

```js
    props: {
      translationFile: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
    mounted() {
      this.$options.translationFile = this.translationFile
    }
```

but any components which depended on this needed to be wrapped with `<client-only></client-only>`